# Aws cloudwatch logs enable for ECS container in rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, aws-sdk, amazon-ecs, amazon-cloudwatch

Am working on Docker based rails application, which is hosted in aws ecs. I wanna enable rails application logs to the cloudwatch.
Please help me it. Your help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

For a docker container running in ECS to send logs to CloudWatch Logs, all you have to do on the docker application side is ensure that the application running in your docker container sends logs to the console (STDOUT/STDERR). Then you need to have your ECS Task Definition configured to use the [awslogs driver](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/using_awslogs.html), and the ECS Execution Role needs the appropriate IAM permissions to send logs to CloudWatch Logs.